# Empty targets in makefile

Tags: makefile

Trying to understand how empty target works and when it is useful.

My makefile:

```
 count_words: size count_words.o
        gcc size count_words.o  -o count_words 

%.o:%.c
        gcc -c -o $@ $<


size: count_words.o
        size $^
        touch size
```

Empty target is `size`. Can't understand why it runs rule when `size` file is deleted, but `count_words.o` is up to date. I suppose that if count_words.o is up to date it should not run size rule, event if size file is deleted, but it does!  `count_words.o` not depends on `size`

When empty target might be useful at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `count_words` target depends on `size`. If the file is missing or
older than count_words, its target is called automatically to
"rebuild" it. You have only the correct behaviour, if you do not delete the 
`size` file.

The size target behaves like a normal target.

As you have only one file, the "empty" target does not make
much sense.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an empty target. Rather an empty file. GNU make is only concerned with whether a file/directory is present and its timestamp.

When make creates or updates `size` that means all `size` dependents become out of date and must be re-built.